# Save or flush ReportLab canvas without closing

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, reportlab

I have a ReportLab script that generates a large PDF file (thousands of pages). This is done in a simple for-loop that creates a page for each iteration.

However, because canvas.save() closes the file for further editing, I have to wait until the for-loop is complete before saving. This means my Python process swells to about 250MB memory usage as the PDF grows in memory - this seems unnecessary from my application's point of view.

Is there a way to save or flush the ReportLab canvas without closing for editing?

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I deal with the same problem, too, but about an order of magnitude larger.  Solution:  the job runs on a Sun server with 32 processor and 24 GB of RAM.  :-/

Comment: Well I'm glad that I'm not missing an obvious API method or something :)

Comment: I don't have a solution either, but I can direct you to this message on python.reportlab.user archives http://osdir.com/ml/python.reportlab.user/2003-03/msg00024.html  Hope this helps